# OrientDb - Select from multiple vertices using graph

Tags: database, nosql, orientdb

I am just starting out with nosql databases, and OrientDB in particular.  My prior experience is with relational databases, mostly with SQL Server.

In MSSQL, I can do something like this:

```
SELECT  s.url, p.title
FROM    Site s
JOIN    Page p ON s.Id = p.SiteId
```

And it will give me a table of all pages, along with the url of the site they belong to:

```
url         |   title
----------------------------
site1.com   |   page1
site1.com   |   page2
site2.com   |   page1
```

Now, in OrientDb, my understanding is that you should use a `link` for a one-way relationship, or an `edge` for a bidirectional relationship.  Since I want to know what pages belong to a site, as well as what site a particular page belongs to, I have decided to use an edge in this case.  The Site and Page classes/vertices are already created in similar fashion, but I can't figure out how to get a similar result set.  From the documentation (https://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/SQL.html):

> OrientDB allows only one class (classes are equivalent to tables in
>   this discussion) as opposed to SQL, which allows for many tables as
>   the target. If you want to select from 2 classes, you have to execute
>   2 sub queries and join them with the UNIONALL function

Their example `SELECT FROM E, V` then becomes `SELECT EXPAND( $c ) LET $a = ( SELECT FROM E ), $b = ( SELECT FROM V ), $c = UNIONALL( $a, $b )`, but that's not what I want.  That results in something along the lines of

```
url         |   title
----------------------------
site1.com   |   
site1.com   |   
site2.com   |   
            |   page1
            |   page2
            |   page1
```

How would I go about creating the original result set, like in MSSQL?

**Additional consideration**: My training and experience with MSSQL dictates that database operations should be done in the database, rather than the application code.  For example, I could have done one database call to get the `s.url` and `s.id` fields, then a second call to get the `p.title` and `p.SiteId` fields, and then matched them up in application code.  The reason I avoid this is because multiple database calls is less efficient time-wise than the time it takes to return the extra/redundant information (in my example, `site1.com` is returned twice).

Is this perhaps not the case for OrientDb, or even graph/nosql databases in general?  Should I instead be making two separate calls to get all of the data I need, i.e. `SELECT FROM Site WHERE Url = "site1.com"` AND `SELECT EXPAND(OUT("HasPages")) FROM Site WHERE Name = "site1.com"`?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select Url, out("HasPages").title as title from Site unwind title
```

Hope it helps

Regards

Comment: Brilliant!  Thank you! I guess wrapping my head around the concept of nosql/graphs got me bamboozled.  Thanks again!